# using moq to populate httpcontext.request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am using the [hanselman tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) to use Moq to create unit tests for methods that take httpcontext as input parameter.

```
public static class MvcMockHelpers
{

    public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);

        return context.Object;
    }

    public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext(string url)
    {
        var context = FakeHttpContext();
        context.Request.SetupRequestUrl(url);  <---- error here
        return context;
    } 



}
```

I am getting the following error on **context.Request.SetupRequestUrl(url);**

*Error  1   'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'SetupRequestUrl' and no extension method 'SetupRequestUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Please help.

I am trying to find a very simple easy to follow tutorial on setting up httpcontext request object and pass into method with context input parameter and be able to create unit test but all the examples in google either do not work or are complicated. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have declared the `SetupRequestUrl` extension method inside the `MvcMockHelpers` class [as shown by the Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/11/05/rhino-mocks-extension-methods-mvc-crazy-delicious.aspx):

```
public static void SetupRequestUrl(this HttpRequestBase request, string url)
{
    ...
}
```

You should have copy-pasted the entire code fragment from the article.

Comment: What are you Googling? The Haacked have shown the method in his blog post. Just Ctrl+F for `SetupRequestUrl` to find it inside his article.